# Keep getting "member reference base type 'string [1000]' is not a structure or union" error and dont know how to fix it?

Tags: c++

This program reads an SSN from the user and checks if it matches an SSN in a text file provided. Tried switching the array to a vector and it didnt work. Tried putting the array in the structure function and using info:: but nothing seems to work. I know this is pretty basic but I cant get it, thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

  struct info{
    string SSN;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
  };

  string list[1000];
  string userSSN;
  char x;
  fstream input(argv[1]);
  int i = 0;
  while(!input.eof()){
    input >> list.x[i] >> list.SSN[i] >> list.firstName[i] >> list.lastName[i];
    i++;
  }
  input.close();

  cout << "Input a SSN:" << endl;
  cin >> userSSN >> endl;
  for(int k = 0; k < i; k++){
    if(userSSN.compare(list.SSN[k]) == 0){
      cout << "Found at location " << k << endl;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're `using namespace std;` and using variable names like `list`? Bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

`list` is just an array of 1000 `std::string`s.  It looks like you need it to be of type `info`. Even that won't solve your problems as `info` has no member named `x`. After that, to access a member of `info` in an array would be like

```
list[i].SSN
```

not

```
list.SSN[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are so many things wrong with this code that I don't know where to start. Let's see:

1. Using `using namespace std;` is almost always a bad idea, and if you have an identifier `list`, then it's even worse because it conflicts with `std::list`.
2. Using `std::string` without `#include <string>` is not guaranteed to work. It *may* work if you include some other standard header, but don't rely on it.
3. Your variable `x` is unused.
4. `string list[1000];` should probably be `info list[1000];`.
5. `list.SSN[i]` et al should probably be changed to `list[i].SSN`.
6. `list.x[i]` does not make sense at all and can probably be removed. (Or you meant to read into the otherwise unused `x` to skip parts of the file.)
7. You cannot read from `std::cin` into `std::endl`. Remove `std::endl` from that line.
8. Using `std::string`'s `compare` function is pretty strange here, just use `==`.

Comment: another mistake is use of `eof` in a loop condition

Answer (score 0):

The issues in your code were already pointed out in other's answers. I'll show you a "working" example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::string;
using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

struct info {
    char x;       // You were reading that from the file so I added it
    string SSN;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;

    friend std::istream &operator>>( std::istream &is, info &i ) {
        // maybe you should check data input somehow...
        is >> i.x >> i.SSN >> i.firstName >> i.lastName;
        return is;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // check if a file name has been passed as a parameter
    string file_name;
    if ( argc < 2 ) {
        cout << "Please, enter the input file name:\n";
        cin >> file_name;
    }
    else 
        file_name = argv[1];

    std::ifstream input(file_name);
    if ( !input ) {
        std::cerr << "Error. Unable to open file: " << file_name << '\n';
        exit(-1);
    }
    // Just use a vector to store all the structs
    vector<info> my_list;
    info temp_info;
    while( input >> temp_info ) {
        my_list.push_back(temp_info);
    }
    input.close();

    cout << "Input a SSN: ";
    string userSSN;
    cin >> userSSN;
    // That's not cheap. You may want to change the container or sort it
    for ( int k = 0; k < my_list.size(); k++ ) {
        if ( userSSN == my_list[k].SSN ) {
            cout << "Found at location " << k << '\n';
        }
    }

return 0;
}
```